# while loop in php not working

Tags: php, while-loop

i am new to php, i am trying to upload a file to a url, where php script should have the logic to check if file already exisits, it should append a value to the file name and then check again if it exisits, if not then proceed further to save it.

Here is the while loop:

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']); 
$i = 1;

while (true) {
    if (file_exists($target_path)) {
        $target_path = $i . "_" . $target_path;
        $i++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, im not sure if break; works the same as in other languages. What i am trying to do is the target path if already exists, will be updated and checked at each iteration of while loop, if it does not exists, the else should break the while loop, and later i will save the file with that name.

It works only if the file does not exisits, after that it just fail to rename the file path.

What is wrong here?

Comment: While(true)?  what are you trying to see if the the value is true?

Comment: So, for `/tmp/xyzzy.txt` you'd get `1_/tmp/xyzzy.txt`? Well, that *is* unlikely to work, yes; you may want to append to `$target_path`, not prepend. The `while` loop seems okay - loops infinitely until the file in `$target_path` doesn't exist.

Comment: Just a heads up, you know as it steps through the loop it will continue to add `$i` to the target_path. For example, if it goes through 3 iterations, the target_path will be `3_2_1_$target_path`, not `3_$target_path`

Comment: that's pretty self explanatory. While true means it will always run infinitely until the break; is called which is called when if is false, i.e no file exists on the disk

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do - is wrong.

Comment: you want to have filenames like "6_5_4_3_2_1_file.txt" ?

Comment: @Rob thank you i got it. I need to change the file name and not the file path, let me test it.

Comment: for instance, you would simplify things by doing "while (file_exists($target_path)) $target_path = $i++ . "_" . $target_path;". And the previous comment seems reasonable for me too: append i's value, don't prepend.

Comment: your while loop should be: `while(file_exists($target_path)) { //do stuff... }`

Comment: What you want to do is check `if (file_exists("$i_$target_path"))`, if it does, just to $i++, else  `$target_path = "$i_$target_path"; break;"` .. And you should be doing that on the basename not the target_path

Comment: @PEdroArthur, thanks yes i will do that. Problem is with prepending it renames after the file extension, but i made a blunder thinking appending it would work, but it rather changes the actual directory path. so thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited, this should work.

```
$i = 1;

$base = basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']);

while (file_exists($target_path.$i.'_'.$base)) {
   $i++;
}

$target_path = $target_path.$i.'_'.$base;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, simple and well understandable for me :)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this little piece of code will help you:

```
function safeFilename($image_path,$filename_original)
{    $extension = strrchr($filename_original, ".");
     $filename_base = substr($filename_original,0,-1*strlen($extension));
     $filename = $filename_base;
     $counter = 1;
     while(file_exists($image_path.$filename.$extension))
     {     $filename = $filename_base . $counter;
           $counter++;
     }
     return $filename.$extension;
}
```

**Update**: my bad, fixed, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This will break badly if a filename has multiple periods in it. I would not recommend this code.